# Mongo aggregation groups and subgroup

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have a Mongo aggregation:

```
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "dateTime" : {
                    "$gte" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"), 
                    "$lt" : ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000")
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : "dateTime", 
                "totals" : {
                    "$sum" : "$payment.totalAmount"
                }, 
                "count" : {
                    "$sum" : 1.0
                }
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
);
```

This works fine. It aggregates, and sums by date range I supplied and I get an output as follows.

```
{ 
    "_id" : "dateTime", 
    "totals" : 2625293.825017198, 
    "count" : 12038.0
}
```

However, I also want to further refine the groupings.
I have a field called 'companyId' and I want to calculate the sum and count by each company Id for the given time range.

I would like to get an output similar to this, where I get a sum and count for each company ID in the date range I queried, not just a sum/count of all the data:

```
[
{ 
    "companyId" : "Acme Co", 
    "totals" : 2625293.825017198, 
    "count" : 12038.0
},
{ 
    "companyId" : "Beta Co", 
    "totals" : 162593.82198, 
    "count" : 138.0
},
{ 
    "companyId" : "Cel Co", 
    "totals" : 593.82, 
    "count" : 38.0
}
]
```

How do I do this? I have not been able to find a good example online.
Thanks

Comment: please provide some data and expected result.

Comment: @turivishal Updated with examples per your comment

Comment: @Cyph : replace `"_id" : "dateTime", ` with `"_id" : "$companyId", ` Do you wanted to get groupBy based on companies along with groupBy on all docs(companies) collectively ?

Comment: @whoami that worked :) thanks. I tried that earlier but missed the '$'.

Comment: @Cyph: You can delete this question as it's just a typo :-)